# How to evenly space out buttons within a table layout?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am attempting to create the view as below. 
[image]

Currently I have the buttons spaced out evenly in my screen but I know that with other devices the situation will not be the same.

I am having trouble evenly spacing out the buttons when I have another button near by it that will activate a tool-tip. Should I use a table layout for this?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: share the layout xml

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use a table layout for this?

A `LinearLayout` is more common and should do the job. Then you just need to add your buttons to it, each with an **invisible** `<view>` between, to set the spacing using `layout_weigth=1`

---

### Example

```
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"/>

  <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

  <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2"/>

  <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

  <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"/>

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```